# What's the remainder of a natual number divided by lcm(m,n)?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $x,m,n \in \mathbb N$, $m,n>0$,

and $x \equiv r \pmod m$,

$x \equiv s \pmod n$ ($r-s \equiv 0 \pmod{gcd(m,n)}$).

It seems $x \equiv r \equiv s \pmod {gcd(m,n)}$;

But $x \equiv ? \pmod {lcm(m,n)}$

Comment: Look at some data.  Try various triples of numbers $(x, m, n)$, and try to formulate a conjecture.  Then, prove it.

Comment: Look at Chinese Remainder Theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general solution first requires that you solve the equation $mu+nv=\gcd(m,n)$.

Then the value is $$x\equiv \frac{(s-r)}{\gcd(m,n)}mu+r\pmod {lcm(m,n)}$$

That might seem a bit gross, but it is just an application of the Chinese Remainder Theorem. It obviously only works if $\gcd(m,n)|s-r$.

It's clear that this $x$ satisfies $x\equiv r\mod m$. substituting $mu=\gcd(m,n)-nv$ shows that $x\equiv s\pmod n$

Comment: Yes, I understand. Thank you.

Comment: @Popopo See my answer for a proof, and derivation of the above formula.

Answer (score 1):

**Existence:** $\rm\ \ d = (m,n)\mid m\mid x\!-\!r,\ \ d\mid n\mid x\!-\!s\ \Rightarrow\ \color{#C00}{d\mid r\!-\!s}\, =\, x\!-\!s-(x\!-\!r)\:$  is *necessary*; $\ $ *sufficient* too: $ $ Bezout $\rm\,\Rightarrow\:\exists\,j,\,k\in\Bbb Z\!:\ kn-jm = r\!-\!s,\: $ so $\rm\  x = s+kn = r+jm\ $ is a solution.

**Uniqueness:** $\rm\:x,x'$ solutions $\rm\!\iff\! x'\equiv x\ mod\ m,n\!\iff\! m,n\mid x'\!-\!x\!\iff\! lcm(m,n)\mid x'\!-\!x.$

**Construction:** $ $ use the extended Euclidean algorithm to find $\rm\:u,v\in\Bbb Z\!:\ um+vn = d = (m,n)\:$ then multiply this equation by $\rm\:(r\!-\!s)/d,\:$ yielding $\rm\:kn-jm = r\!-\!s,\:$ then proceed as above. This yields the formula in the answer of Thomas (general CRT = Chinese Remainder Theorem).

Comment: Thank you, I have improved my question.